# cmake "make install" to remote machine?

Tags: linux, installation, cmake

With `make install` I can copy my binaries, configs etcetera to a target folder for execution.

Now I have the following situation: we have a virtual machine setup as a **build host**, and a different real Linux machine as a **target platform**.

I would like to have `make install` copy the files directly in a folder on my remote machine (via `scp` or similar). How can I achieve that?

Comment: Well, let make execute `scp`.

Answer (score 7):

You often could do

```
 make install DESTDIR=/tmp/mydest/
```

then archive that destination directory

```
 tar czvf /tmp/mydest.tgz -C /tmp mydest
```

then copy that archive to the remote place

```
 scp /tmp/mydest.tgz remote:tmp/
```

at last, untar the archive at the remote and copy it at appropriate place

Comment: Actually I would like to prevent all these intermediate steps. I guess cmake uses a copy (cp) command to copy files. There MUST somehow be a way to tell cmake to use scp instead...

Comment: Often the source comes with a file named "README". The contents of that file might give a clue. For example pcre-8.39 suggests to use `make dist` and/or `make distcheck` to make tarballs.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Why not untar directly at the appropriate place without the copy step?

Answer (score 3):

Using cmake 2.8.14, command "add_custom_command" into the CMakeLists.txt, can be also used :

```
add_custom_command(TARGET my_target POST_BUILD COMMAND scp $<TARGET_FILE:my_target> user@remote_host:dest_dir_path )
```

Advantage : only call when the target is rebuild.

Comment: " only call when the target is rebuild." So I use [--fresh option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-fresh)
This is my example with key (no login-password) 
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND scp -i "/home/user/my_nonpublic_ssh_key" "/home/user/CppProjs/QThread-with-moveToThread_console/build-cross/QThread-with-moveToThread_console" remoteuser@"192.168.122.8:/home/remoteuser" )

Answer (score 2):

`make` can operate with a specific prefix during installation:

```
  make prefix=$dest/usr install
```

A solution to your problem is to

- mount the filesystem of the target machine on your build machine. This can be done via nfs (persistent) or via sshfs (easier),
- set $dest to the mountpoint and run the command above

Comment: prefix doesn't seem to do anything. DESTDIR works (as in the other answer.) However, mounting is the way to go to make it all work at once (and the server can be remote using an SSH mount for out of local network computers.)

Answer (score 1):

I am using this solution:

```
install (CODE "execute_process(COMMAND scp -r -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/. user@remote:/path/to/copy/)")
```

Then I run command `make install` and it's works

I know that *${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}* not best variable for it but for me it's fine

Answer (score 0):

With `user` a userprofile on the machine `remote` and a ssh key preperly configured :

```
  install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND /usr/bin/rsync -avh ${INSTALL_DIR} user@remote:/home/user/)")
```

Copies the locally installed binaries on the remote only when make install is invoked.